# Ngnix Unknown Directive

Tags: nginx

Using Ubuntu on Amazon EC2. I am getting this error message when restarting server:

```
unknown directive "ec2-54-201-86-229.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:3
```

I am following these instructions on installing wordpress:

http://theartofcode.tv/installing-wordpress-on-ec2/

My default.conf file is

```
server {
    ## Your website name goes here.
    ec2-54-201-86-229.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
    ## Your only path reference.
    root /var/www/;
    listen 80;
    ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    include conf.d/drop;

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;


        }

        location ~* \.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires 1d;
        }



}
```

Please note i am a complete noob ! any ideas from the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `server_name` directive before your websites' name:

```
server_name ec2-54-201-86-229.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
```

Comment: ok that works and the nginx restarts without errors but I still can't access my site even if I followed that tutorial to the letter. Any guides on how I can troubleshoot possible errors?

Comment: You need to open port 80 http://stackoverflow.com/a/10454688/5269463

Comment: ok this works! I have a working wordpress installation. The only thing I am worried is security and because I am such a noob, I might just forget the whole thing.. though I have everything I need to move my site :(